# To deploy a Tiny ML model that I created via Colab Google

Tags: tensorflow, arduino

When I compile the code (on arduino) I get the following error:

> 8 bytes lost due to alignment. To avoid this loss, please make sure the tensor_arena is 16 bytes aligned.

```
constexpr int tensorArenaSize = 8 * 1024;
byte tensorArena[tensorArenaSize];
```

Someone can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: So, basically the bus width might be 16-bit and thus due to the master slave communication protocol (probably using I2c) it might be losing 8 bytes due to some alignment issue with the memory. The tensor might be 16-byte aligned which seems weird because mostly it should be 8-byte or double word aligned. Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 0):

For reasons unbeknownst to me, the compiler wants to make sure your large byte array is 16-byte-aligned.  Because of variables already declared above the two lines you included, it needs to "move forward" the Large Array by 8 bytes, to make it start at an address that is on a 16-byte boundary.  To fix the error (to me this should just be a warning) either add a dummy 8-byte variable before your Large Array, or **move** 8-byte worth of variables from before your Large Array to after it.  In the first case you just lose 8 bytes of variable space.

Comment: Thank you for your help @mmixLinus. I will try the solutions you provide to me.